# Expression evaluation sequence

Tags: expression, evaluation

Why is the below code printing 25. I would guess it should print 28 instead. Can someone please evaluate it step by step as a computer would do. Thanks.

```
class MultiAssign
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int k = 1;
        k += (k = 4) * (k + 2); // or k = k + (k = 4) * (k + 2);
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sequence in which operations will take place. You will notice that value of k will be changed to 4 only after you have written k=4...Before that statement value of k will remain 1